# Mono not working

Tags: macos, homebrew, sound-volume

I had 2 versions of Mono installed, one via Homebrew, the other downloaded from Mono website (http://www.mono-project.com).

This was causing issues with versions, so I tried removing both.

I uninstalled Homebrew with `brew uninstall mono` and the other one with

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework
sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.mono-MDK.pkg
sudo rm -rf /etc/paths.d/mono-commands
```

(as per website instructions.)

I then re-downloaded and installed the latest package from http://www.mono-project.com. It installed successfully, but when I try to `mono` from Terminal, I get `/usr/local/bin/mono: No such file or directory`

I tried `brew unlink mono` and `brew rm mono`, but still nothing.

Comment: I have only used mono once and it was glitchy.  I believe there is Visual Studio(or whatever they call it) for mac now.  That would surely work better.

Comment: I need it to run other packages, not for development

Answer (score 4):

Solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542535/how-to-install-mono-on-macos-so-mono-works-in-terminal

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/:${PATH}
```